# adding CDN links for javascript in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

i tested some javascript code without any variables and loops and it worked fine. it only  used  `

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.min.css">`
<script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which i got from cdn and the html only had this

### html for pop image

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="img/bigboy.jpg" data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="img/bigboy.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    <a href="img/smallboy.jpg" data-lightbox='lo' > <img src="img/smallboy.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    <a href="img/crazyboy.jpg" data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="img/crazyboy.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    <a href="img/crazyboy.jpg" data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="img/crazyboy.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    <a href="img/smallboy.jpg" data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="img/smallboy.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    <a href="img/bigboy.jpg" data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="img/bigboy.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    <a href="img/bigboy.jpg" data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="img/bigboy.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    
    
    
</div>
```

[image]
what i need is to apply it on this code

### html in laravel

```
     @foreach($posts as $post)
      ...................
        <div class="gallery">           
     <a href="/storage/{{$post->image}}"  data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}"  data-lightbox='lo'id = "img-posts" alt=""> </a>
<div>
   .....................
     @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to place the CDN links at the bottom of your `body` element. This ensures that they wont hold up the rendering of other elements on your page.

```
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.min.css">`
  <script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Additionally, you'll want to move the `<div class="gallery">` OUTSIDE of the loop otherwise you'll wrap each image up in the gallery wrapper.

Here's how you should do it:

Note I also changed the image `id` attribute to a `class` as ids need to be unique.

```
<div class="gallery">   
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <a href="/storage/{{$post->image}}" data-lightbox='lo'>
      <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" class="img-posts" alt="">
    </a>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: it still cant bring the desired output...  could it be because of the foreach loop somehow

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @logicalrap Not sure why there's a `data-lightbox='lo' ` attribute on the `<img>` element, your "_html for pop image_" example doesn't have this.

Comment: @kerbh0lz good find, I copied it out of the "html in laravel" example